# Horizontal Gradient with a rounded rect path?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, core-graphics, gradient

I have a custom UIView I'm drawing using CoreGraphics. Using CoreGraphics, how would I set a horizontal gradient and clip it to my rounded rect path while still using a shadow? I wrote as much as the path and I can fill it with a color using setFill, but the gradient (a horizontal one, too) isn't abiding by the path...

EDIT: Since the time of posting (not so long ago), I figured out how to do a complex horizontal gradient, so now my only problem is drawing it within my CGContext's path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems I've found my own answer:

```
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPt, endPt, 0);
```

Those lines of code perfectly clip it to the path of a rounded rect, or any path desired.

Comment: `ClosePath` is for closing an open subpath. If `path` is already closed, `ClosePath` will do nothing. Unless `path` is specifically a partial path for some reason (in which case you should change its name to something more specific), the time to close the path is when building the path in `path`, not afterward.

Comment: In my case, it was an open subpath, and I took your note into account and did a little refactoring of my code :D